# How to use environment variable in urlrewrite.xml of tomcat rewrite file

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat8, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a urlrewrite.xml which I want to use to redirect an url

```
    <rule>
        <from>/http</from>
        <to redirect="true">https://www.example.com</to>
    </rule>
```

I want the example.com to be coming from a java system variable which I have set at startup, however it didnt work. This is the code I modified to use the java system variable 'exampleurl'

```
    <rule>
        <from>/http</from>
        <to redirect="true">${exampleurl}</to>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is just an alternative What I have tried.
This will help if you use same thing multiple times in the same file.

```
[<!ENTITY exampleurl "127.0.0.1">]
```

Add the above line to DOCTYPE line like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd" [<!ENTITY exampleurl "127.0.0.1">]>
```

Use &exampleurl; like below:

```
<rule>
    <from>/http</from>
    <to redirect="true">&exampleurl;</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: This doesn't pull a java system variable like the OP is asking for.

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed to mention it was an alternative I tried.